# How to use Fourier table to derive result

Tags: fourier-transform

Using this Fourier-transform taken from a table;
$$ \mathcal{F}\big\{\frac{1}{1+t^2}\big\} \Longrightarrow \pi e^{-|\omega|}  $$

I would like to transform this expression;
$$ g(x) = U_0 \frac{L^2}{L^2+x^2}, \quad L,U_0>0 $$

I know that

$$ \mathcal{F}\big\{ U_0f(x) \big\} = U_0\mathcal{F}\big\{ f(x) \big\} $$

Then I thought that maybe I should rewrite it as

$$ g(x) = U_0 \frac{1}{1+(x/L)^2} \Longrightarrow \hat g(\omega)=U_0\pi e^{-|\omega/L|}$$

But the correct answer is

$$ \hat g(\omega)=U_0 \pi L e^{-|\omega|L} $$

Why is my approach wrong, and where should I rethink?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I'll fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you rescale the $x$ variable, there is a factor that comes out of the Fourier transform (and the scaling of frequencies goes the other way around):
$$\mathcal F \{f\left(\frac x L\right)\}(\omega)=|L|\mathcal Ff(L\omega)$$

Comment: That's one crazy equality, I'll give you the green tick for it. One question though, is that equality valid for every Fourier transform, or only this one?

Comment: It's not that crazy. Try to write the definition of the Fourier transform as an integral, then change the variable. You'll see where it comes from.

Comment: This is true for all Fourier transforms. That's in 1 dimension. If your functions are defined on $\mathbb R^n$ then the scaling becomes $|L|^{n}$.

Comment: Finally, note that this is consistent with the Heisenberg uncertainty principle (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). As $L$ grows, the signal's support becomes wider, while in frequency, the Fourier transform's support becomes narrower.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! If my function is defined on $\mathbb R^n$, and the scaling becomes $|L|^n$, does the RHS then become $|L|^n \mathcal F f(L^n \omega )$?

Comment: No, it becomes $|L|^n\mathcal Ff(L\omega)$.